# Let $A = \{\frac{1}{n} \in\mathbb{R}\, :\, n=1,2,3,...\}\cup\{0\}$. What are the accumulation point(s) of $A$?

Tags: real-analysis

In the real-analysis lecture, the lecturer left this as an exercise:

> Let $A = \{\frac{1}{n} \in\mathbb{R}\, :\, n=1,2,3,...\}\cup\{0\}$. Prove that the only accumulation point is $0$.

The set $A$ is equivalent to $[0,1]$ from what i see. I know that the accumulation points of $[0,1]$ are $0$ and $1$. So why $0$ is the only accumulation point of $A$?

Comment: *“The set $A$ is equivalent to $[0,1]$“* – what does that mean?

Comment: For $n=1$, $\frac{1}{n} = 1$. And for $n=2,3,...$, we have the points in $(0,1)$. $A$ is $\{0\}\cup (0,1)\cup \{1\}$ in this case. Am i wrong? @MartinR

Comment: $A$ is a *strict subset* of the interval $[0, 1]$. As an example, $A$ does not contain the points $2/3$ or $1/\pi$. Also $A$ is countable, and the interval $[0, 1]$ is not countable.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for enlightening me, I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: For any $x\ne 0$ you can find some deleted neighborhood of $x$ that does not have any intersection with $A$.

Comment: Alternative approach: define $~a_0 = 0, ~$ and for $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ define $~a_n~$ equal $~1/n.~$  Then, the sequence $\langle a_n\rangle ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}~$ is clearly convergent, with limit $~0.~$  There is a theorem in Real Analysis that any convergent sequence with limit $~L~$ has exactly one accumulation point, namely $~L~$ itself.

Comment: @DyakoSoltanian Like if $n=2$, we have $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and if we choose $\varepsilon 
 >0$ small enough we get $D(x,\varepsilon )-\{x\}$, which doesn't include both $0$ and $\frac{1}{3}$, right?

Comment: @Nana, Correct! Actually if you choose $\epsilon \le 1/2-1/3=1/6$, then that deleted neighborhood does not contain any $1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\left\{a_n\mid a_n=\frac{1}n , n=1,2,3,... \right\}\cup \{0\}$$

(1). $0$ is an accumulation point. Since $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N=\left\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right\rceil, \forall n>N\Rightarrow |a_n-0|<\epsilon$

(2). $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ are not accumulation point, since $\forall n, \exists\epsilon=\frac{1}{2n(n+1)}$, such that the interval $(a_n-\epsilon, a_n+\epsilon)$ only contains a single point $a_n$, hence all $a_n$ are isolated points.

(3). $\forall x\in[0,1]\cap x\notin A, \exists n,$ such that $a_{n+1}<x<a_n$, hence $\exists\epsilon=\frac{1}4(a_n-a_{n+1})$, such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\cap A=\emptyset,\Rightarrow x$ is not an accumulation point.